# Unable to read repository at https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site

Tags: eclipse, selenium, testng

I am trying to install TestNg in my eclipse but am facing the below issue. Could any one please help me in this even i tried all the ways but I am unable to fix this problem.

I am using latest version of eclipse and TestNG

```
Unable to read repository at https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/content.xml.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Please share your testng.xml  and pom.xml files

Comment: See if this helps: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/2348

Answer (score 2):

Download the testNG JAR files from https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse and then manually add it to eclipse IDE as follows:

- Download the respective TestNG JAR Folder and unzip it.
- Help > Install New Software > Add > Click Archive and add the Unzip folder path here and click Add folder.
- TestNG should now be available for installation, select the check box and click next

Comment: this is a great answer. Too bad people have not noticed it.

Comment: I want to confirm that this approach works with Eclipse 2023.03 and TestNG [plugin for eclipse 7.4.0.202106051955

Comment: Adding one more info that.. u have to select content.jar while choosing file

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and all i did was to download a newer version of JDK
:
old version : 1.8.40
current version : 1.8.201
then tried again to install TestNG and it worked